# Maximum independent edge set in multipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

The [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) finds a maximum matching of an undirected, unweighted *bipartite* graph $G=(E,V)$ in $\mathcal{O}(|E|\sqrt{|V|})$ operations. Is there a generalization fo $k$-partite graph?

Comment: What's unsatisfactory with the generalizations cited in that Wikipedia article?

Comment: By sheer curiosity, really. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but while the Edmonds algorithm has the same asymptotic running time, it is in practice more complex.

Comment: So perhaps you are hoping for nice bounds on the constant in terms of $k$?

Comment: Yes, that would be nice!

Comment: If you were to consider that edges of alternating paths alternate between _two_ states, matched and unmatched, then it is not really surprising that matchings would have a nice structure on bipartite graphs. No other $k$-partite graphs disallow cycles of odd lenghts, so I doubt there is any significantly simpler algorithm than the one for general graphs.